# R: "Error in match.arg() : 'arg' should be of length 1"

Tags: r

There's another person's package's function I'm trying to debug. Inside it's arguments, theres one named `qrule`, which has different choices.

E.g, the function looks like this:

```
my_function <- function(arg1, arg2, etc, 
                        qrule=c("math","school","shahvaish","hf1","hf2","hf3","hf4"), ...)
```

For debugging, I'm running the code from inside the function, assigning objects or values for each argument. The problem is with `qrule` argument. The first time it shows up inside the function's code, it is presented like this:

```
if (is.character(qrule)){
    qrulename<-paste("qrule", match.arg(qrule),sep="_")
    qrule<-get(qrulename, mode="function")
  }
```

Running the code, I have

```
qrule=c("math","school","shahvaish","hf1","hf2","hf3","hf4") #first, create the vector  

 is.character(qrule)
[1] TRUE #Since is TRUE, next two lines of code must be executed
qrulename<-paste("qrule", match.arg(qrule),sep="_")
Error in match.arg(qrule) : 'arg' must be of length 1
```

I tried replacing qrule with the first option (since the first is the default option), but I get a similar error:

```
qrulename<-paste("qrule", match.arg("math"),sep="_")
Error in match.arg("math") : 'arg' should be one of
```

I would like to know two things:

1. Why do I get this error?
2. Why this line of code works fine calling the function from the outside but throws this error from the inside of the function code block?

Comment: First, `match.arg` without the choices argument can only be used inside a function.  so outside of the function you should do `match.arg('math', qrule)`

Comment: Thanks @onyambu. Following your input, I can do `qrulename<-paste("qrule", match.arg("math", qrule), sep="_")`, but then the following line `qrule<-get(qrulename, mode="function")` gives me the error message "Error in get(qrulename, mode = "function") : 
  object 'qrule_math' of mode 'function' was not found"

Comment: That is because of environment problem. The functions are defined in the package and not in the global environment. If you know the package name, try running `package_name:::qrule_math` and see whether its an error or not

Comment: Thank you; the three dots gave me the chance to keep working on the problem!